# How to disable in PhpStorm/WebStorm auto line breaks if insert brace "{"

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I have trouble in .js or .vue or .php and other different extensions

For example, I have that:

[image]

Then I press `{` button (for insert that symbol), and see that (immediately):

[image]

I already tested all settings of PhpStorm, but problem is stayed...

Mac OS Catalina 10.15.3 (19D76) / JetBrains PhpStorm 2019.3.1 and 2020.1 EAP (anyway)

Comment: 1) So you are having it even in plain `.php` file (PHP context, not JavaScript)? Or that has to be JavaScript/Vue context? 2) Just in case: please post your `Settings/Preferences| Editor | General | Smart Keys` 3) What custom plugins (not bundled by default) do you have installed? If you disable them all and restart IDE -- does issue persist?

Comment: 1) Yes in php too, even in .txt file
2) Smart keys I checked many times
3) Good idea! I will check plugins.
Thank you!

Comment: If you have fixed it -- better post your solution / what was wrong as an answer (you can accept it later) -- will help others in similar situation.

Comment: Already published. Bottom of my post. "I fixed it!

Plugin IdeaVim works correct, but his config file ~/.ideavimrc contains line: source ~/.vimrc who init incorrect behavior."

Comment: No. Do it as a proper **Answer** -- it's then clearly visible that the question has some solution .. and if you accept the answer .. it gives even more "weight" / visibility.

Comment: @LazyOne Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### I fixed it!

Plugin IdeaVim (for JetBrains products) works correct, but his config file `~/.ideavimrc` contains line: `source ~/.vimrc` who init incorrect behavior.